# Is it possible to commit without showing up in the log?

Tags: git, github

I am using Github Pages to host a website, and what I want to do is to use a cron job on my local machine to run a bash script that changes certain files in the remote repository without showing up in the log. The reason I want to do this is because Github Pages only allows static pages, and I need to have a dynamic sitemaps among other things. I don't want it to show up in the log, because the script would have to be run quite frequently, which would spam the log.

I realize that this is against the nature of git, but is there any way to do it?

Comment: Maybe `got commit --amend` will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite current change and than force push it.
If you cooperate with others, this method is not recommended.

```
git commit -a --amend
git push -f
```